# How to use Stub Api in order to create AuthSession records in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, stubapi

My Main method :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void  endUserSession(Id userId){
    List<AuthSession> uSessions = [ select Id , UsersId FROM  AuthSession  WHERE  UsersId =:userId AND  IsCurrent = TRUE ];
    if (!uSessions.isEmpty()) {
        // Delete the session(s)
        delete uSessions;
    }
}
```

Since the obj AuthSession is read only , here's how i modified my method using the Stud API , i created a class that implements StubPrrovider :

```
@isTest
public class MockProvider implements System.StubProvider {

    public static List<AuthSession> sessionsList;

    public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName, 
        Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, List<String> listOfParamNames, 
        List<Object> listOfArgs) {

        if (stubbedMethodName == 'querySessions'){
            return sessionsList;
        }
    return sessionsList;
    }
}
```

class :

```
public class DistributedMSelector {
 public static AuthSelector aselect;

    public static  void endSessions(Id userId){
        List<AuthSession> uSessions = new List<AuthSession>(); // Initialize the list
        for(AuthSession u: aselect.querySessions(userId)){
            uSessions.add(u);
        }
       if (!uSessions.isEmpty()) {
            // Delete the session(s)
            delete uSessions;
        }
    }
}
```

AuthSelect :

```
public class AuthSelector {
 public List<AuthSession> querySessions(Id userId){
        return [ select Id , UsersId ,IsCurrent FROM  AuthSession  WHERE  UsersId =:userId AND  IsCurrent = TRUE ];
    }
}
```

And the MockUtil class :

```
public class MockUtil {
    private MockUtil(){}

    public static MockProvider getInstance() {
        return new MockProvider();
    }

     public static Object createMock(Type typeToMock) {
        // Invoke the stub API and pass it our mock provider to create a 
        // mock class of typeToMock.
        return Test.createStub(typeToMock, MockUtil.getInstance());
    }
```

finally , the test method :

```
@IsTest
    static void testAuthSession() {
          Id profileId = [Select Id, Name from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' OR Name='Administrateur système'].Id;

   User testUser = new User(
        FirstName = 'Test',
        LastName = 'User',
        Email = 'aaaaa@example.com',
        Username = 'azzeze@example.com',
        Alias = 'tuser',
        CommunityNickname = 'testuser',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
        ProfileId = profileId // Replace with a valid Profile Id
    );
    insert testUser;
        String AuthSessionJson= '[{"UsersId":'+' "' + testUser.Id +'" ' +' , "IsCurrent":"true"}]'; 
 List<AuthSession> authSessions = (List<AuthSession>)JSON.deserialize(AuthSessionJson, List<AuthSession>.class);

   Id userId = authSessions[0].Id;
   MockProvider.sessionsList = (List<AuthSession>)JSON.deserialize(AuthSessionJson, List<AuthSession>.class);
        DistributedMSelector.aselect = (AuthSelector)MockUtil.createMock(AuthSelector.class);
        DistributedMSelector.endSessions( testUser.Id);
    }
```

when run the test method it shows : **System.ListException: Invalid id at index 0: null**
the issue is on             `delete uSessions;`

Answer (score 0):

The way you had a Selector class to mock SOQLs, you'd require similar implementation to mock DML calls.

The idea here is to tell the system the delete call is mocked. Since did not have any such implementation, the system tries to delete AuthSession which don't even exist because they were mocked with dummy values.

```
public class AuthDatabase {
    public List<AuthSession> deleteSessions(Set<Id> userIds){
        delete [ SELECT Id FROM  AuthSession WHERE  UsersId IN: userIds AND  IsCurrent = TRUE ];
    }

    public List<AuthSession> deleteSessions(AuthSession[] sessions){
       delete sessions;
    }
}
```

Update MockProvider:

```
public class MockProvider implements System.StubProvider {
    public static List<AuthSession> sessionsList;

    public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName, Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, List<String> listOfParamNames, List<Object> listOfArgs) {
        if (stubbedMethodName == 'querySessions'){
            return sessionsList;
        } else if(stubbedMethodName == 'deleteSessions'){
            return sessionsList;
        }
    return sessionsList;
   }
}
```

Now the way you mocked querySessions call, mock the DML as well,

```
DistributedMSelector.authDb = (AuthDatabase)MockUtil.createMock(AuthDababase.class);
```

And in DistributedMSelector add authDb & replace the DML to use the non-static method we created.

```
if (!uSessions.isEmpty()) {
    // Delete the session(s)
    authDb.deleteSessions( uSessions );
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148678/discussion-on-answer-by-sachin-hooda-how-to-use-stub-api-in-order-to-create-auth); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.